# Spark with Cython

Tags: python, pyspark, cython

I recently wanted to use `Cython` with Spark, for which I followed [the following reference](https://www.4info.com/Blog/October-2014/Enhancing-Spark-with-IPython-Notebook-and-Cython).

I wrote the following programs as mentioned but I am getting a:

```
TypeError:
fib_mapper_cython() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

## spark-tools.py

```
def spark_cython(module, method):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        global cython_function_
        try:
            return cython_function_(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            import pyximport
            pyximport.install()
            cython_function_ = getattr(__import__(module), method)
        return cython_function_(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped()
```

## fib.pyx

```
def fib_mapper_cython(n):
    '''
     Return the first fibonnaci number > n.
    '''
    cdef int a = 0
    cdef int b = 0
    cdef int j = int(n)
    while b<j:
        a, b  = b, a+b
    return b, 1
```

## main.py

```
from spark_tools import spark_cython
import pyximport
import os
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
pyximport.install()


os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/home/spark-1.6.0"
conf = (SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('Fibo'))

sc = SparkContext()
sc.addPyFile('file:///home/Cythonize/fib.pyx')
sc.addPyFile('file:///home/Cythonize/spark_tools.py')
lines = sc.textFile('file:///home/Cythonize/nums.txt')

mapper = spark_cython('fib', 'fib_mapper_cython')
fib_frequency = lines.map(mapper).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b).collect()
print fib_frequency
```

I get a `TypeError` whenever I run the program. Any Ideas?

Comment: The fib_mapper_cython initial values would loop indefinitely. Changing b = 1 should fix the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a `Cython` nor a `PySpark` issue, you unfortunately added an extra function call during the definition of `spark_cython`. Specifically, the function that wraps the call to the `cython_function` is called with no arguments on return:

```
return wrapped()  # call made, no args supplied.
```

As a result you won't return the wrapped function when you execute this call. What you do is call `wrapped` with no `*args` or `**kwargs`. `wrapped` then calls `fib_mapper_cython` with no arguments (since `*args, **kwargs` are not supplied) hence the `TypeError`.

You should instead:

```
return wrapped
```

and this issue should no longer be present.

Comment: Thanks for the help