# should declare import fib.pyx or not?

Tags: python, pyspark, cython

in this example https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/faq/cython.html

The author posted this code

```
import pyximport
import os

pyximport.install()
import fib
```

When I included the import my pyx module, it always complains 
ImportError: No module named pyx_module

I looked at other sample code, like 
https://www.4info.com/Blog/October-2014/Enhancing-Spark-with-IPython-Notebook-and-Cython
[Spark with Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965248/spark-with-cython)

No one else shows this import statement. Should you be able to import the pyx module like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is pyximport and how should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764232/what-is-pyximport-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that this duplicate is what you want. However if it isn't what you want then the question should probably be closed as "unclear what you're asking" instead

Answer (score 0):

short answer is yes. you should call import pyx_module.

The reason I got confused is because I am using in a Spark code which uses zip files to pass dependencies, and the sc.addPyFiles call does not work with zip files, and import always fails.